# Applet: XML can't find DTD

Tags: java, xml, applet, dtd

I'm writing a applet that uses a DTD file to check the content of the XML it receives.

I had the problem of the DTD not placed in the right folder with the applet viewer, but now that I'm testing this on the server I get the same error again.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: 
    access denied (java.io.FilePermission/leveldtd.dtd read)
```

How can I fix this when the applet is on the server?

---

```
public static void parseThis(InputSource is) throws Exception{
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLHandlerLevel myExampleHandler = new XMLHandlerLevel();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);
        /* Begin parsing */ 
        xr.parse(is);
    }
```

XML parser creation.

Comment: BTW - how are you invoking the applet viewer?  From an IDE?  Launched by Ant?  The command line?  Also: what JDK version are you using (or more precisely, what is the version of whatever it is that the applet viewer is coming from)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an applet to get a resource from a server, it must use an URL.  File objects will not work because:

1. The `File` object will point to a place on the computer of the **user.**
2. It requires a trusted applet to use `File` objects.  Hence the `AccessControlException` in your output.

URLs to resources can easily be formed using the `URL(baseURL, pathString)` constructor where the base URL is obtained from `Applet.getDocumentBase()` or `Applet.getCodeBase()`.

> ..how do I give the URL to the parser ?

Here is a code snippet taken from [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) that uses an XSD located inside one of the Jars.  The URL is stored in `schemaSource`.

```
try {
    URL schemaSource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("JNLP-6.0.xsd");
    System.out.println( "schemaSource: " + schemaSource );

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory =
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
    factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", true) ;
    factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", true) ;
    factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema-full-checking", true);
    factory.setAttribute(
        "http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-noNamespaceSchemaLocation",
        schemaSource.toString());
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    factory.setValidating(true);

    InputStream schemaStream = schemaSource.openStream();
    try {
        StreamSource ss = new StreamSource( schemaStream );
        String language = XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI;
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(language);

        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(ss);
        factory.setSchema( schema );
    }
    finally {
        schemaStream.close();
    }

    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    documentBuilder.setErrorHandler( errorHandler );

    InputStream is = page.openStream();
    try {
        document = documentBuilder.parse( is );
    }
    finally {
        is.close();
    }

    List<LaunchError> parseErrors = errorHandler.getParseErrors();
    xmlValid = parseErrors.isEmpty();
    errors.addAll(parseErrors);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.err.println( "Error: " + e.getMessage() );
    // TODO Show to user
}
```

Comment: Sorry this might sound stupid but how do I give the URL to the parser ? uptil now the parser would read that there was a dtd in the xml and would look for it so I never needed to do anything with the dtd

Comment: @Jason:  You're going to have to be a lot more specific than that.  Pretend for a moment that I *can't* see your code.  E.G. Where are the JavaDocs for the parser?

Comment: :P sorry about that I added some code to my post, let me know what more you need

Comment: @Jason:  See the edit to my question.  If that does not solve the problem for you, I suggest you start a new question related to "Validate XML using a DTD from URL".